# Changes after Pull Request

Tags: git, github

I made a Pull Request for a GitHub project but it was rejected because of some changes which were recommended to me. Now I can see that after my pull request there are others request which are made and merged. My question is what are the exact steps I should do to be sure that my local clone is up to date with all the other stuff going on the real repo. These are the steps I did:

1. Forked a GitHub project
2. Cloned it locally
3. Created a topical branch
4. Made a few changes
5. Committed and pushed the changes
6. Then from GitHub I pressed the Pull Request button and my Pull Request was on the list of requests (so basically everything was successful).

I run `git pull origin master` inside my branch and it said that everything is up to date. I run `git checkout master` and did the last step and the output was the same - everything is up to date but I can see that there are other merged request after mine. My suggestion is that this is because I fork the repo.

So reading about syncing a fork with the original repo are the steps described here https://help.github.com/articles/syncing-a-fork/ what I need in this situation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the [link you mentions](https://help.github.com/articles/configuring-a-remote-for-a-fork/) describes, you need to add a remote for the original repository, if you want to sync your local `master` branch and bring it up to date:

```
git remote add upstream https://github.com/ORIGINAL_OWNER/ORIGINAL_REPOSITORY.git
# and then
git fetch upstream
```

You can replace `upstream` with any name you want.  After this, follow the steps you would normally take to bring a local branch up to date.  If you wanted to do this via merging, you could do:

```
git checkout master
git merge upstream/master
```

At this point, your local forked `master` branch should be up to date with the latest original `master`, and then warnings in GitHub should have gone away, allowing your reviewer to complete the pull request.